# MySQL WHERE IN Or Filter Using C # List

Tags: c#, mysql, list

Basically I have a List of IDs (Int32) in a C# Class.  When a user logs into our application I need to check the List of IDs against a list on a MySQL Innodb table to see if they have access to these Ids.

Which method is best in terms of performance.  Iterate around the List in C# to check the IDs exist or perform the checks in a WHERE IN clause in the MySQL query ?

Comment: Perform the checks in a `WHERE IN` clause. That way if you get a result from the MySQL query you know the ID exists.

Comment: Following on from my post above, the problem I now have is using the query SELECT COUNT(*) Ids FROM MyTable WHERE Ids IN ('1,3,2,4,2') will return a COUNT of 1, either though the Ids 4 didn't exist.  How can I overcome this problem